# How to fix time in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, date, time

I am currently using Arch Linux as my OS on my desktop. When I look at my time, it is 22:38, when the time clearly is around 17:08. When I invoke the command `timedatectl`, I get:

```
Local time: Wed 2017-01-11 22:37:43 IST
Universal time: Wed 2017-01-11 17:07:43 UTC
    RTC time: Wed 2017-01-11 17:07:41
    Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
```

---

**Update**

When I run `sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`, I get:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-01-11 00:49:36 IST; 1 day 1h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 31123 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─31123 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Jan 12 01:39:42 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 5.9.78.71:123 (1.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:39:53 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.53.103.108:123 (1.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:03 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 139.59.19.184:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:13 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 139.59.45.40:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:24 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 123.108.200.124:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:34 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 125.62.193.121:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:44 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 139.59.45.40:123 (3.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:40:55 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 123.108.200.124:123 (3.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:41:05 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 139.59.19.184:123 (3.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Jan 12 01:41:15 sharan-pc systemd-timesyncd[31123]: Timed out waiting for reply from 125.62.193.121:123 (3.arch.pool.ntp.org).
```

---

**traceroute**

I also tried the command `traceroute -U -p ntp pool.ntp.org`, and I get:

```
traceroute to pool.ntp.org (139.59.19.184), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.114.1.1 (10.114.1.1)  1.713 ms  2.020 ms  2.343 ms
 2  10.10.2.41 (10.10.2.41)  1.123 ms  2.580 ms  2.836 ms
 3  cyberoam.iisc.ac.in (10.10.1.98)  0.553 ms  0.806 ms  0.813 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

---

How do I fix this? I've even tried `timedatectl set-ntp true`. Am I supposed to reboot for this to take effect?

Comment: good work.  Google says cyberoam is a brand of (web-filtering?) firewall.  It is not uncommon for your university to use an internal NTP server for their own computers, and it's quite possible you have access to those.  (Apparently Windows PCs using Active Directory will use the domain controller as an NTP server).  University of York had a very similar setup IIRC.  I can't find *any* documentation about your IT on the IISC website unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like SERC handle your campus IT. They have some Linux instructions although nothing about NTP, maybe you can get directed to someone who will help? http://nitss.iisc.ac.in/ and http://www.serc.iisc.in/facilities/support/

Comment: @sourcejedi Thanks so much, you've gone above and beyond what is needed for an SE answer.

Comment: Related bug report on systemd's GitHub: [Can't sync time when time is incorrect due to dnssec](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5873)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

systemd-timesyncd will not require you to reboot.  I've tested timedatectl on my system.  It might be necessary to wait a minute for a connection.

man timedatectl

> status
>
> Show current settings of the system clock and RTC, including
>              whether network time synchronization is on. *Note that whether
>              network time synchronization is on simply reflects whether the
>              systemd-timesyncd.service unit is enabled.* Even if this command
>              shows the status as off, a different service might still
>              synchronize the clock with the network.

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Wed 2017-01-11 13:45:07 GMT
  Universal time: Wed 2017-01-11 13:45:07 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2017-01-11 13:45:07
       Time zone: Europe/London (GMT, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: yes
```

timedatectl manpage is lying on my system.  Possibly the implementation was patched by Fedora, without patching the manpage.  I do not know how to query which service is used; my system happens to use chronyd.  I imagine it might also be possible to use ntp/ntpd.

However in your case I would be quite confident that Arch uses the upstream default of timesyncd.

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; disabled; 
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)

$ systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-01-09 19:09:39 GMT; 1 day 18h ago
 Main PID: 928 (chronyd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
           └─928 /usr/sbin/chronyd
```

You might have errors logged underneath the status.  Make sure to run `systemctl` as a user with access to the system journal, e.g. using `sudo`.

Unlike chronyd with `chronyc`, there is no documented way to additionally query `systemd-timesyncd` for... anything really, beyond "NTP synchronized: no".  Hope it has useful logs!

I suggest aiming to

1. Identify which well-known `pool.ntp.org` alias your system is trying to use.
2. Test the alias e.g. `ntpdate -q arch.pool.ntp.org`.
3. `traceroute` to the alias to see if there is a nearby block i.e. a firewall preventing access.  As always, I would use `ping` first because it gets results quicker (and is less prone to mis-interpretation), or use the `mtr` version of traceroute (this also defaults to ICMP traceroute, which avoids lots of output from multi-path networks).  Ultimately you want something like `traceroute -U -p ntp pool.ntp.org`, i.e. using the same UDP port as NTP does.

**EDIT**: previous versions of this answer were confused about systemd-timesyncd's default NTP servers.  Although they are commented out (disabled) in `timesyncd.conf`, it should only be necessary to uncomment the line if you need to change the server.  The default values are built in to timesyncd at compile time.  This is mentioned in all documentation.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd

Comment: Take a look above. I have queried `sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` and it seems like I have some `timed-out` logs. Do I have to `traceroute` now?

Comment: just used `traceroute` and got a few results. How can I use `traceroute` with `ping`?

Comment: On my fresh install of Archlinux `systemd-timesyncd.service` was not running. I started and enabled it and now the time on my machine is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Did time zone is correct for your location? And you should set the correct time zone via timedatectl set-timezone

The **date** command is showing system time, for your current location.

**ntpdate** will correct time for your time zone.

for example use apple ntp server will result:

```
sudo ntpdate time.apple.com

11 Jan 19:18:28 ntpdate[1052]: adjust time server 17.253.38.125 offset 0.004981 sec
```

Comment: timezone will not fix "NTP synchronized: no"